Armature copy woes: weird transform keeps applying when going between modes
Blender 4.2
I imported an fbx (animated character).  I created my own custom mesh, then duplicated the imported armature.  Because my mesh is a Y pose, I made some edits to align the bones to my mesh.  Created a rest pose, parented my mesh to the duplicated armature.
When I change modes, the custom mesh keeps transforming away from the origin.  I have gone into pose mode, selected all bones, cleared all transforms (model snaps back to origin) and it all looks OK until I change modes again.
I have tried copying the entire original graph to my duplicate, but I'm stuck - don't know why this is happening or how to correct it.
The animation which is also a copy of the original, is way messed up and offset as well.
Will try to link to the model here.
Thanks for reading
Blend file. located on mega service.

Somehow, there was an offset in Pose Mode. While in Pose Mode, clearing all transforms set the armature to 0,0,0. Now, when I bind the mesh, edit, etc., all is well (no weird transforms). I also had to delete existing keyframes for this to work.

Note: When I try to link the animation data from the imported model to my custom mesh, the offset returns.  The imported animation plays fine, so I don't understand where the offset happens or why/how it continues to be a problem.  In the meantime, I will re-create the poses manually.
